# How can I use this font not only in math mode?

Tags: fonts, document-classes

I'm trying to change the font in one text, but it only applied to math mode. I want it in everything. Adding `\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}` should do the trick. The preamble as it is now:

```
\documentclass[b1]{sciposter}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, euscript}               
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}    
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler, dsfont}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
%\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{subfig, float, caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

I don't know what I should add or remove for it to work. I have another text which has the font applied to everything, here is the preamble:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
      \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, euscript}
      \usepackage[brazil]{babel}
      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
      \usepackage{indentfirst}
      \usepackage{multicol}
      \usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler, dsfont}
      \usepackage{graphicx}
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      \usepackage{stackrel}
      \usepackage{cancel}
      \usepackage{enumerate}
      \usepackage{subfig, float, caption}
      \usepackage{shadethm}
      \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
      \usepackage{thmtools}
      \begin{document}
      Test.
      \end{document}
```

Some time ago, I had some trouble with that last preamble because I had forgotten to remove the `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` or something like it. Maybe the problem is because of the document class?

Comment: `\usepackage{gfsartemisia}`

Comment: I already have `\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}` there. Also, separating `\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler, dsfont}` into two didn't work. Changing `gfsartemisia-euler` to `gfsartemisia` only didn't work either.

Comment: @egreg Why? `gfsartemisia-euler` seems to work fine. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class switches the default font to sans, the font package sets only the serif font. If you want to use serif for a poster, you can switch it back:

```
\documentclass[b1]{sciposter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\renewcommand\familydefault\rmdefault
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

[image: custom serif]

Comment: I knew it was something about the class! Thanks. It works.

Comment: @IvoTerek Yep! Beamer does the same. It is common for classes intended for use in presentations and displays, where sans is often recommended.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[b1]{sciposter}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, euscript}
\usepackage{amsmath}           
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}    
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{subfig, float, caption, kantlipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\Large
\kant[1-2]

\begin{equation}
e^{At}=\\ 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
3e^{-t}-3e^{-2t}+e^{-3t} & \dfrac{5}{2}e^{-t}-4e^{-2t}+\dfrac{3}{2}e^{-3t} & \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-t}-e^{-2t}+\dfrac{1}{2}e^{-3t} \\[1em]
-3e^{-t}+6e^{-2t}-3e^{-3t} & \dfrac{-5}{2}e^{-t}+8e^{-2t}-\dfrac{9}{2}e^{-3t} & \dfrac{-1}{2}e^{-t}+2e^{-2t}-\dfrac{3}{2}e^{-3t} \\[1em]
3e^{-t}-12e^{-2t}+9e^{-3t} & \dfrac{5}{2}e^{-t}-16e^{-2t}+\dfrac{27}{2}e^{-3t} & \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-t}-4e^{-2t}+\dfrac{9}{2}e^{-3t} 
\end{array} 
\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The standard for `sciposter` is to use the sans-serif font as default, so you should add your font preceded by `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}` as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: Doesn't matter whether it precedes it or not.

Comment: @cfr Yes, it's only a matter of preference.